# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied on using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper with pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl wheel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I usually use *virtualenv* and *virtualenvwrapper* for creating virtualenvironments for my projects. On trying to create a new virtualenvironment using the following command:

```
mkvirtualenv -a . -p python3.7 venv
```

I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv/seed/via_app_data/via_app_data.py", line 75, in _get
    self.app_data,
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv/seed/embed/wheels/acquire.py", line 28, in get_wheels
    acquire_from_bundle(processed, for_py_version, wheel_cache_dir)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv/seed/embed/wheels/acquire.py", line 57, in acquire_from_bundle
    copy2(str(bundle), str(bundled_wheel_file))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 263, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1/3.7/wheels/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl'

created virtual environment CPython3.7.9.final.0-64 in 257ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/cosine, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
Setting project for cosine to /home/ubuntu/cosine_similarity
```

With the virtualenvironment being created still, on running :

```
pip -V
```

I get

```
pip 20.1 from /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Which is pip associated with the default python version on the server and therefore, I uninstalled **python3.7**, and on running `python3.7` on my terminal got:

```
Command 'python3.7' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python3.7-minimal
```

Thus on the assumption that python3.7 wasn't installed properly, I again re-installed it using the ppa from deadsnakes as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install python3.7
```

But sadly I am still running into the same error, I am using poetry on top of the virtualenvironment and on running the following:( I have the poetry.lock file)

```
poetry install
```

I get the following error message:

```
[CalledProcessError]
Command '['/home/ubuntu/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cosine-similarity-SzdRNlpw-py3.7/bin/python', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Would be great if someone can explain why this is happening and how to solve this in turn, thanks.

**[EDIT]**

Adding more information when I use `-p python3.6`, I don't get any such **permission errors** and my virtualenvironment is created successfully.

For additional information, I installed **python3.8** on the system using the above *ppa by deadsnakes** and then attempted to create a virtualenvironment with python3.8.

> Command
> `mkvirutalenv -a . -p python3.8 venv2`

The output in stdout is as follows:

```
created virtual environment CPython3.8.5.final.0-64 in 627ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv2, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv2/bin/predeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv2/bin/postdeactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv2/bin/preactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv2/bin/postactivate
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts creating /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv2/bin/get_env_details
Setting project for venv2 to /home/ubuntu/main_xyz/app
```

Comment: @aaron : The output of `ls  -l /home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data` is `total 4
drwxrwxr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 May 15 23:51 v1.0.1
` and for `echo $USER` is `ubuntu`

Comment: `ls: cannot access '/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1/3.7/wheels/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl': No such file or directory`, hmm... I wonder why though

Comment: `ls -l /home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1/3.7/wheels` shows           `total 2056
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1489786 May 14 10:02 pip-20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  582683 May 14 10:02 setuptools-46.1.3-py3-none-any.whl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   26502 May 14 10:02 wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
`

Comment: `which python`  outputs `/usr/bin/python` and `python3.7 --version` outputs `Python 3.7.9`

Comment: That appears to not be in an activated virtualenv.

Comment: Oh for the activated virtualenv `which python` outputs `/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv/bin/python`

Comment: The outputs are as follows: `python3.7 --version` outputs `Python 3.7.9` ,  `which pip` outputs `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/pip` and `pip --version` outputs `pip 20.2.2 from /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
`

Comment: Does `mkvirtualenv -a . -p python3.7 venv` still give an error?

Comment: Yes, it still gives the same error, the output for `which python`, `which pip`, `pip --version` that I gave you where from the same problematic **virtualenvironment**. I recreated another **virtualenvironment** with name *venv2* and it also gives the same error. No such error if I change the python version to **3.6** by using `-p python3.6`

Comment: @aaron: I just installed **python3.8** and then did `mkvirtualenv -a . -p python3.8 venv` and it created the environment successfully, I'll add the outputs for the same in the question

Comment: So only `-p python3.7` has the error?

Comment: Yeah I only get the error with `-p python3.7`, `-p python3.8` , `-p python3.6` , etc work for me

Comment: Sounds to me like there are some strange folder permissions or ownerships set. You could try something like this to check if there are ownership problems:

`find /home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1/3.7 -exec ls -l {} \; | grep " root "`

The reason for the error could be that for some reason part of the path to the .whl file belongs to root and you cannot write into that path.

Answer (score 3):

Before you try this solution, try running `sudo su`
Then repeat your solution,... If it works cool. Else

Part 2 ======>

Check your python version.
`python --version`

Find all python within python
`ls /usr/bin/python*`

If python 3.7 is part of the listed path, cool.

Set python default path
`alias python='/usr/bin/python3.7'`

Re login your source
`. ~/.bashrc`

Confirm that your version of python has changed
python --version

Then install virtual environment
`pip install virtualenv`

Then create a virtual environment
`virtualenv venv`

And activate it
`source venv/bin/activate`